# How do I fill a tinyMCE textarea in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny, tinymce

I'm trying to fill the textarea in this tinyMCE example from within R.

It looks like I should be writing to output$textHolder

But my statement in the observe() function isn't doing it.

I'm using the example from the tinymce site.

I can't find much support on this one.

Here is my server code:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {


    observe({
      print ("observe")
      output$textHolder = renderText("XXX")

    })

  output$htmlText <- renderUI({
    req(input$typedText)
    HTML(enc2utf8(input$typedText))
  })

  output$rawText <- renderText({
    req(input$typedText)
    enc2utf8(input$typedText)
  })
})
```

And here is my UI code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      useShinyjs(),
      tags$script(src='https://cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js')
    ),

    fluidRow(
      titlePanel("tinyMCE Shiny"),
      br(),
      column(width=6,
             tags$form(method="post",
                       tags$textarea(id="textHolder")
             ),
             br(),
             actionButton("fetch", "Get Results!", icon=icon("lightbulb-o"),class="btn-primary",
                          onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('typedText', tinyMCE.get('textHolder').getContent());"),
             tags$script("tinymce.init({
                         selector:'#textHolder',
                         theme: 'modern',
                         height: 200,
                         plugins: ['advlist autolink link image lists charmap preview hr','wordcount',],
                         menubar: true,
                         toolbar: 'undo redo | bold italic | bullist | link',
                         });")
  ),
  column(width=6,
         tags$style(HTML('pre {height:240px;}')),
         tags$label(`for`="rawText", "Raw String"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(textOutput("rawText")),
         br(),
         tags$label(`for`="htmlText", "HTML Version"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(htmlOutput("htmlText"))
  )
      )
  )
)
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to fill that text area with. Does the text area need to change or is it to be static? Currently, your `observe` doesn't take in any values from the `input` environment and so will never update. It's also not really meant to be used to include a statement updating the `output` environment. An answer here should be quite simple but it's not clear what your desired behavior is. If the text area doesn't need reactivity, it becomes even easier. Please expand on your expected behavior.

Comment: Did you consider using: https://github.com/mul118/shinyMCE ?

Comment: stanekam: Basically I need to allow user to input data in a tinyMCE window, move the data to permanent storage, then write the stored data back into the tinyMCE window.

Comment: does the answer below work for you now?

Answer (score 1):

You could consider using the shinyMCE package: https://github.com/mul118/shinyMCE. (Use e.g. `devtools::install_github("mul118/shinyMCE")` to install).

On ui side you would use:

```
tinyMCE('editor1', 'Click to edit text')
```

and on server side you can access the html code via `input$editor1`.

Below I integrated the code in your app.

[image]

**Full example would read:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMCE)

server <- function(input, output, session) { 

  output$htmlText <- renderUI({
    req(input$editor1)
    HTML(enc2utf8(input$editor1))
  })

  output$rawText <- renderText({
    req(input$editor1)
    enc2utf8(input$editor1)
  })
}

ui <- shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
      titlePanel("tinyMCE Shiny"),
      br(),
      column(width = 6,
             tinyMCE('editor1', 'Click to edit text'),
             br(),
             actionButton("fetch", "Get Results!", icon=icon("lightbulb-o"),class="btn-primary",
                          onclick = "Shiny.onInputChange('typedText', tinyMCE.get('textHolder').getContent());")
  ),
  column(width = 6,
         tags$style(HTML('pre {height:240px;}')),
         tags$label(`for`="rawText", "Raw String"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(textOutput("rawText")),
         br(),
         tags$label(`for`="htmlText", "HTML Version"),
         hr(),
         tags$pre(htmlOutput("htmlText"))
  )
      )
  )
)


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Very interested in shinyMCE but
if (!require("devtools"))
  install.packages("devtools")
devtools::install_github("shinyMCE", "mul118")

produces: Error in parse_repo_spec(repo) : 
  Invalid git repo specification: 'shinyMCE'

Comment: seems to be a docu issue. Using `devtools::install_github("mul118/shinyMCE")` should work.

Comment: No, I still can't install shinyMCE on my Windows10 computer in RStudio

Comment: If you send me your contacts I'll forward the error logs.